# Jquery Dialog Open event not firing

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a aspx page with two panels having the same class, which should function as dialog box. I am trying to open the dialog box using dialog("open") but it doesn't seem to work.
Below is the code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".descPanel").dialog({ autoOpen: false,
            open: function() {
                $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");
            }
        });

        $('.image').mouseover(function() {
            $($(this).parent()).children('.descPanel').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML Strcuture:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr id="tr">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Jquery/Untitled.jpg" CssClass="image" />
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="mypanel" CssClass="descPanel">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="mylabel" CssClass="label" Text="hello"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr id="tr">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Jquery/Untitled.jpg" CssClass="image" />
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" CssClass="descPanel">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" CssClass="label" Text="hello1111"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

I have verified that the element that points to the dialog has been reffered correctly. Any solutions so that I can get it working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overall your code should look like this instead:

```
$('.image').each(function() {
  var panel = $(this).siblings('.descPanel');
  $(this).mouseover(function() {
    panel.dialog('open');
  });
});    
$(".descPanel").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function() {
        $(this).siblings(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WxpNc/).

*Why?* Well when you call `.dialog()` it wraps that `<div>` in another set of elements, but more importantly it's *moves* those elements to the end of the `<body>`, so they're not there to find relatively anymore.  In the above we're finding the panels that go with the images and storing a reference to them *before* they're moved.

As an aside, you should remove that `id="tr"` from your code, duplicated IDs are only trouble! (and invalid HTML), use a class in those situations.

Comment: sorry Nick. I didnt format well while asking the question. It is ui-dialog-titlebar. I have edited the question now. Moreover i am not able to add the full code in the question. It doesnt accept.

Comment: @Kunal - Ah I see your error, your question needs more editing to reveal the HTML, one moment.

Comment: Nick can u help me format the question. My full question doesnt look like that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kunal - yup, already done, and updated the answer to match your actual issue here, was apparent after seeing all the code :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. First thing i am using a asp:repeater in my code, so it will repeat the HTML and hence the tr gets the same ID. Thanks for a very quick reply. Can you just tell me why did u put the each function. I dont want to loop throught all the images. I just want to open the dialog for the image on which the mouse is hovered.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot :). Got the whole idea. That was great! :)

Answer (score 5):

Just found out that you can also bind a function to the `open` event by doing:

```
yourDialog.bind("dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, to listen for dialog creation globally. Cheers :)